# MS Access - deleting records using multi-select Listbox

Tags: forms, vba, listbox, multi-select

I would like to use a multi-select Listbox form control in Access (2007) to delete multiple records in an unbound Table. The Listbox is made up of Dates (dd/mmm/yy) so I need to write code that can understand date types but I've struggled to find the right code out there that matches my requirements. Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated!

Here is the code that I have attached to the OK Command button on the Form which I can't get it to work:

```
Private Sub cmdOK1_Click()
    Dim vItem       As Variant
    Dim strSet      As String
    Dim i           As Long

    strSet = ""

    With Me.lstPeriod
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSet = strSet & "','" & .ItemData(vItem)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    'Remove the first comma
    strSet = Mid(Trim(strSet), 2, Len(strSet) - 1)

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblDataConsolidation WHERE Period IN (" & strSet & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    For i = 0 To lstPeriod.ListCount - 1
        lstPeriod.Selected(i) = False
    Next

    For i = 0 To lstPeriod.ListCount - 1
        lstPeriod.Selected(i) = False
    Next

    lstPeriod.Requery
    lstPeriod.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try **Debug.Print** and see what you get from looping through the listbox? Also your DELETE is missing an `*` specifying what to delete from the table.

Comment: @PaulFrancis The '*' is actually not necessary

Comment: @PaulFrancis where does the Debug.Print go?

Comment: I get this VBA error message when I press the Command button: Run Time Error 3075: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Period IN (,'01/04/2014','01/05/2014)'. Not sure what this means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with Dates, you need to make sure that the Dates are enclosed between `#` tags, and to be sure that the dates are in the **MM/DD/YYYY** format. So the following code should work,

```
Private Sub cmdOK1_Click()
    Dim vItem       As Variant
    Dim strSet      As String
    Dim i           As Long

    strSet = ""

    With Me.lstPeriod
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSet = strSet & "," & Format(.ItemData(vItem), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
            End If
        Next
    End With

    'Remove the first comma
    strSet = Trim(Right(strSet, Len(strSet) - 1))

    If MsgBox("You are about to DELETE records from the table. This process is not reversible." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblDataConsolidation WHERE Period IN (" & strSet & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    For i = 0 To lstPeriod.ListCount - 1
        lstPeriod.Selected(i) = False
    Next

    For i = 0 To lstPeriod.ListCount - 1
        lstPeriod.Selected(i) = False
    Next

    lstPeriod.Requery
    lstPeriod.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats great it worked with the dates format, thanks @PaulFrancis! Is there also a way to bring up a pop-up box to confirm the deletion of records?

Comment: You can add a message box to get confirmation. I have modified the code. Please check the updated answer. Please mark the `Answer` with a Green tick so others could find it useful too. Thanks.